# Visual Studios sln file SolutionProperties or Performance?

Tags: visual-studio

I am working on a team project using Mercurial as our version control. Recently, I noticed that after a pull and merging the latest changes into my branch, the following change appears in the .sln file.

```
GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
    HideSolutionNode = FALSE
EndGlobalSection
```

changes to:

```
GlobalSection(Performance) = preSolution
    HasPerformanceSessions = true
EndGlobalSection
```

There are no noticable differences, everything seems to build OK, but I am unsure if this change will cause any potential problems. We are also confused as to why this change happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe HideSolutionNode is true by default, until you add a second project to the solution (at least with vs2010 and probably 2012.)  HasPerformanceSessions is probably due to someone trying to run the profiler on the code.  Neither of these should impact the compilation of your solution.